# formatting is incorrect in last row

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a Tag Cloud type deal on my website and when you go to look at 1 tag

Example:

[image]

notice the first row looks like its spaced by 2 spaces and the last row is spaced by 1.

CSS

```
.tabcontent{
display:none;
}
```

Code

```
$tag_movies_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tagname='$n' AND movie > 0");
$total_times_used_movies = mysql_num_rows($tag_movies_result);
<div id="movies" class="tabcontent">
<?php if ($total_times_used_movies > '0') { ?>     
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
    <?php    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tag_movies_result))
    {
    $movies_to_tag_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id=".$row['movie']." ORDER BY name ASC");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($movies_to_tag_result))
    {
    ?>
    &nbsp;<a href="./movie.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row['name']; ?> (<?php echo $row['year']; ?>)"><img src="./images/movies/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.jpg" width="150" height="150" border="0" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" /></a>    
    <?php } } ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php }else{ ?>
        NO MOVIES WITH THIS TAG.
    <?php } ?>    
    </div>
```

yet on this page http://i51.tinypic.com/ncms9c.png it uses the same exact code and displays correctly

Comment: I viewed this in Firefox and Chome... I don't see what you're talking about, but you should know it looks really weird in Chrome, might be worth checking out.

Comment: will do, try it in IE, thats what im viewing it in, i will download chrome right now. it actually show you it in chrome? tells me they are still reviewing my site. wow they check your website at the most unoportune time lmao let me take some pics i guess. 1 sec sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be to scrap the table completely, convert all those `<td>`s to `<div>`s and just give them the CSS `float:left;`. For this demo I just put the CSS inline, but you'll want to put it in a CSS file when you get this working.

```
<div id="movies">
    <?php if ($total_times_used_movies > '0'):  ?>

        <!-- Also add css to set the width to 25% of 'movies' width, including borders, margins, padding, etc -->
        <div style="float:left;">

    <?php   
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($tag_movies_result)):
            $movies_to_tag_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id=".$row['movie']." ORDER BY name ASC");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($movies_to_tag_result)):

    ?>
        &nbsp;<a href="./movie.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row['name']; ?> (<?php echo $row['year']; ?>)"><img src="./images/movies/<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.jpg" width="150" height="150" border="0" alt="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" /></a>    

    <?php 
            endwhile; // movies to tag result
        endwhile; // tag movies result
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php else: ?>
            NO MOVIES WITH THIS TAG.
    <?php endif; ?>    
</div>
<!-- END movies -->
```

Comment: i see what you are getting at but then i would have to write all kinds of new css to re-lay it out, as it is with your format it doesnt layout correctly.

Comment: A Div format is much more easy to maintain and manipulate than that of a table. I think it would be worth the extra time.

Comment: yeah i know what you are saying but i gotta go redo the rest of my layout now :D as it now it looks like http://i51.tinypic.com/i70cu9.png with yours, and its still double spaced.

Comment: Just add consistent width and margins to the div and it will format correctly :)

Comment: yeah was hoping for an easy table fix, but yeah, just added a `<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>` under each of the new `</div>`